# Refused to load the script '...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: express, vercel

I deployed my serversite code in vercel, but my site replied with status code 404 and give this error message:  Refused to load the script 'https://conoret.com/dsp?h=car-doctor-server-bay-rho.vercel.app&r=0.47386382518756887' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. what can I do to solve this problem.

I and to get my server site data .